# Проблема копирования из list в list и удаление элемента из list

Tags: c++

Есть проблема в методе класса. Надо переписать нужный объект класса из одного list в другой и удалить в одном. Но оно полностью не рабочее, не пойму в чем проблема.

Описание класса:

```
class storage { // склад
private:
   int size;
   provider provider;
   list <Medicine> medic;
   list <Medicine> sell_medic;
public:
   storage(int size);
   void sell();
   void show_storage();
   void add();
   void report();
   ~storage(){ }
};
```

Описание класса Medecine:

```
class Medicine {//лекарство
public:
   string name;
   float price;
   string group_medicine;
   Manufacturer manufacturer;
   Medicine() { }
   Medicine(string name, string group_medecine, float price, Manufacturer manufacturer);
   ~Medicine() { }
```

};
Содержание list:

```
    Medicine("Ketorol Gel","Противовоспалительная Мазь", 62.7,Manufacturer("Dr.Reddy`s")),
    Medicine("Тизин","Капли для носа",43.15,Manufacturer("ФАРМАР ОРЛЕАН")),
    Medicine("Engystol","Противовирусное",205.1,Manufacturer("Хаймиттель")),
    Medicine("Stripsils intinsive","Противовоспальтельное",35.6,Manufacturer ("RIL")),
   Medicine("Уролесан","Противоспалительное",73.2,Manufacturer("ARTHERIUM")),    
  Medicine("Цистон","Противовоспалительное",105.58,Manufacturer("Himalaya")),
    Medicine("Sinuforte","Спазморасширяющее",477.8,Manufacturer("Lab.Reig Jofre")),
```

Описание нужного метода:

```
void storage::sell() {
    string sell_name;

    cout << "\nВведите имя продаваемого товара" << endl;
    cin >> sell_name;

    copy_if(medic.begin(), medic.end(), back_inserter(sell_medic), [sell_name](const Medicine& med) {
        return med.name == sell_name;
    });

    auto result = remove_if(medic.begin(), medic.end(), [sell_name](const Medicine& med) {
        return med.name == sell_name;
    });

    medic.erase(result, medic.end());
}
```

Comment: "Но оно полностью не рабочее" - бессмысленный набор слов. Приведите вменяемое описание проблемы.

Comment: @AnT То и означает, что не выполняет ту логику, которую я заложил. Потому, что при проверке list <Medicine> sell_medic - он все равно пустой и, получается, что метод не сработал

Comment: Так может он и должен быть пустым? Если у вас изначально нет такого имени в исходном списке, то результат поиска будет пустым. Нам отсюда не видно, что у вас там за вход.

Comment: @AnT Почему? Я вызываю STL метод копирования с предикатом и он должен копировать по определенному критерию. И точно так же удалять.

Comment: @AnT Я изначально подразумеваю о случаях когда есть такое имя

Comment: Это прекрасно, что вы их "подразумеваете". А что получается *в реальности*? Что у вас сидит в списке? Что вы вводите в качестве `sell_name`?

Comment: @AnT Правил текст

Comment: Ну как бы понятно, что у вас скорее всего оператор `==` возвращает "не равно" там, где вы ожидаете равенство. А уж из-за чего это происходит: проблемы с кодировкой, или вы вводите вообще что-то не то - нам отсюда не видно. Попробуйте для начала только латинские названия.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужна всего одна строчка кода:

```
sell_medic.splice(sell_medic.end(), medic,
                      std::find(medic.begin(), medic.end(), sell_name));
```

Чтобы найти в cписке элемент добавить в другой список и удалить из первого.